# Suppress column names from Netezza Select statement

Tags: linux, netezza

How to suppress column heading and end from Select statement in Netezza?

```
Select Column_type from _v_sys_columns where table_name = 'EMP';
```

**Output:**

```
Coulms
------- 
EMP_NM
EMP_SAL 
row count(2)
```

I want to suppress Column name (`Columns  ------`) and `row count(2)`.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is fairly vague as to what you are attempting to do or what the issue is. I highly recommend reading through these as pages:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer they are both fantastic resources to use when asking or answering questions and will help you get the best answers quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The method for accomplishing this depends on the interface/application you are using.  It's not clear from  the sample output you give which you are using, but I'll venture a guess that you are using the nzsql CLI. For it, you can toggle the output of column headers (along with the trailing row count) using the \t directive.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select table_name, type_name from _V_SYS_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME like 'EMP%';
 TABLE_NAME |       TYPE_NAME
------------+-----------------------
 EMPLOYEES  | BIGINT
 EMPLOYEES  | BIGINT
 EMPLOYEES  | CHARACTER VARYING(50)
 EMPLOYEES  | NUMERIC(20,2)
 EMP_NM     | BIGINT
 EMP_SAL    | BIGINT
(6 rows)

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> \t
Showing only tuples.

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select table_name, type_name from _V_SYS_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME like 'EMP%';
 EMPLOYEES  | BIGINT
 EMPLOYEES  | BIGINT
 EMPLOYEES  | CHARACTER VARYING(50)
 EMPLOYEES  | NUMERIC(20,2)
 EMP_NM     | BIGINT
 EMP_SAL    | BIGINT
```

Alternatively, you can invoke nzsql with the "-t" option for the same effect.

Comment: Thanks ScottMc G .  "-t" option is working. Thanks lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just omit the header's (Not just by using `NETEZZA` as far I know). You will have to use some OS command to strip the extra lines. Like, if you are currently running `NZSQL` in `LINUX` then probably you can use `tail` and `head` command to get the desired output

```
nzodbcsql -h <hostname> -d <db name> -u <userid>  -pw <password> -q "Select Column_type from _v_sys_columns where table_name = 'EMP'"| tail -3 | head -2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nzsql -h ${host_name} -u ${user} -db ${dbname} -pw ${password} -A -t -c " 
 select table_name, type_name from _V_SYS_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME like 'EMP%';"
```

it will trim the headers and align the output